# File upload using Apache wink REST service

Tags: java, rest, apache-wink

I want to upload file using REST Service in Apache wink.

I am using HTTP client.

```
org.apache.wink.client.ClientConfig clientConfig = new org.apache.wink.client.ClientConfig();

    javax.ws.rs.core.Application app = new javax.ws.rs.core.Application() {
           public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
               Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
               classes.add(RestResource.class);
               return classes;
           }
    };
    clientConfig.applications(app);
    org.apache.wink.client.RestClient client = new org.apache.wink.client.RestClient(clientConfig);    

org.apache.wink.client.Resource resourceCreateProductImage = client.resource("http://restResource/uploadProductImage");
    File file = new File("/home/aspire17/Pictures/Product.png") ;
    String fileName = file.getName();   
        MultipartEntity multiPartEntity = new MultipartEntity();

       multiPartEntity.addPart("fileName", new StringBody(fileName != null ? fileName : file.getName())) ;

       FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(file, "application/octect-stream") ;
        multiPartEntity.addPart("attachment", fileBody) ;


    ClientResponse responseCreateProductImage = resourceCreateProductImage
.contentType("multipart/form-data").accept("*/*").post("");
```

and my apache wink rest service is like,

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Path("/uploadProductImage")
public JSONObject uploadProductImage(BufferedInMultiPart bimp) 
   throws IOException, JSONException  {

    OutputStream out = null ;
    Random rand = new Random();
    List parts = bimp.getParts();
    Debug.logInfo("parts size : " + parts.size(), module);
    Iterator it = parts.iterator();
    byte[] bytes = null;
    while(it.hasNext()){
        InPart name = (InPart) it.next();
        try{
            InputStream inputStream= name.getInputStream();
            out = new FileOutputStream("/home/aspire17/Pictures/Product.png");
            int read=0;
            bytes = new byte[1024];
            while((read = inputStream.read(bytes))!= -1){
                out.write(bytes, 0, read);
            }
            inputStream.close();
            out.flush();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){
        }

    }
}
```

I can't figure out, how can i get file in Rest service

Right now, as i run this service i am getting below exception

> [java] 2013-05-29 18:59:14,784 (http-bio-0.0.0.0-8080-exec-2)[StandardWrapperValve.java:269:ERROR] Servlet.service() for servlet
>   [restServlet] in context with path [/restAPI] threw exception
>        [java] java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException
>        [java]   at java.lang.System.arraycopy(Native Method)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.multipart.MultiPartParser.shiftBuff(MultiPartParser.java:80)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.multipart.MultiPartParser.fetch(MultiPartParser.java:201)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.multipart.MultiPartParser.verifyByteReadyForRead(MultiPartParser.java:183)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.multipart.MultiPartParser.digestBoundary(MultiPartParser.java:144)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.multipart.MultiPartParser.nextPart(MultiPartParser.java:105)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.common.model.multipart.InMultiPart.hasNext(InMultiPart.java:83)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.common.model.multipart.BufferedInMultiPart.(BufferedInMultiPart.java:50)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.multipart.BufferedInMultiPartProvider.readFrom(BufferedInMultiPartProvider.java:62)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.common.internal.providers.multipart.BufferedInMultiPartProvider.readFrom(BufferedInMultiPartProvider.java:39)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.registry.ServerInjectableFactory$EntityParam.getValue(ServerInjectableFactory.java:200)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.common.internal.registry.InjectableFactory.instantiate(InjectableFactory.java:68)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.CreateInvocationParametersHandler.handleRequest(CreateInvocationParametersHandler.java:44)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleSubResourceMethod(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:183)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindResourceMethodHandler.handleRequest(FindResourceMethodHandler.java:110)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.FindRootResourceHandler.handleRequest(FindRootResourceHandler.java:95)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.HeadMethodHandler.handleRequest(HeadMethodHandler.java:53)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.OptionsMethodHandler.handleRequest(OptionsMethodHandler.java:46)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.handlers.SearchResultHandler.handleRequest(SearchResultHandler.java:33)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.ResourceInvocation.handleRequest(ResourceInvocation.java:92)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.log.Requests.handleRequest(Requests.java:76)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:26)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.RequestHandlersChain.handle(RequestHandlersChain.java:22)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.doChain(AbstractHandlersChain.java:63)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.handlers.AbstractHandlersChain.run(AbstractHandlersChain.java:48)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequestWithoutFaultBarrier(RequestProcessor.java:207)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.RequestProcessor.handleRequest(RequestProcessor.java:154)
>        [java]   at org.apache.wink.server.internal.servlet.RestServlet.service(RestServlet.java:119)
>        [java]   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
>        [java]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
>        [java]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>        [java]   at org.ofbiz.webapp.control.ContextFilter.doFilter(ContextFilter.java:337)
>        [java]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
>        [java]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
>        [java]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
>        [java]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
>        [java]   at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
>        [java]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
>        [java]   at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
>        [java]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
>        [java]   at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
>        [java]   at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
>        [java]   at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1002)
>        [java]   at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:585)
>        [java]   at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
>        [java]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>        [java]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>        [java]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

Comment: Try with `content-type` as `multipart/mixed` in the client.

Comment: @Dmahapatror, In wink framework not supporting multipart/mixed. What I add in server side?